# Mac OS X Shortcut Maximize window

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-snow-leopard

Is there really no way that I can maximize or unmaximize a window in Mac OS X with just the keyboard? (Currently using 10.6.3)

Comment: [osx - Maximize window to full screen on OS X - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/278452/maximize-window-to-full-screen-on-os-x) (I updated my answer to add a list of 17 apps that support something like this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [RightZoom](http://www.switchingtomac.com/tutorials/make-the-os-x-maximize-button-work-like-windows/) which is a freeware application for exactly that purpose: It provides the possibility to define a keyboard shortcut for maximizing windows and can override application specific behavior for the green resize button to make it consistent for all apps.

Answer (score 2):

Most Applications have "Zoom" or "Zoom window" commands under a "Window" menu or equivalent. I think the most straightforward solution is to type the following in the terminal:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSUserKeyEquivalents '{"Zoom" = "@^Z"; "Zoom Window" = "@^Z"; }'
```

That command will set the default keyboard shortcut to <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>

Comment: How do I undo this? And how do I take a different keybinding, e.g. CMD+F5?

Comment: This will override all previously defined `NSUserKeyEquivalents` in the `NSGlobalDomain`, i.e. all keyboard shortcuts defined for *All Applications* in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Application Shortcuts*. It's safer to use the preference pane for this.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you don't want to install another program...

And

2. you have the window of interest minimized into the dock (genie or scale effect)...

And

3. you don't want to take your hand off the keyboard or rely on the mouse...

Then |>

step 1:::: use `cmd` + `tab` to focus on the application in finder, which will focus on it but not maximize it...

step 2:::: use `ctrl` + `F2` to focus on the menu bar...

step 3:::: arrow right to expand the Window menu...

step 4:::: arrow up (quickest) to highlight the minimized window of interest...

step 5:::: press enter to "maximize" it back into its original position.

If you want it truly maximized by definition, it would need to be maxed before minimizing it into the dock, but it works to achieve that quick snapping I want without 3rd party software.

Comment: By the way, ^this works ONLY if the application has a Window menu >> for example, it won't maximize Docker Desktop because there ain't one. I prefer the mouse once in a blue moon to a third party app; except I do us Spectacle for snappy snapage.

Answer (score 1):

I use [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/). Lots of functions via Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't mind running an additional program in the background, which I can see being a dealbreaker, try using [SecondBar](http://blog.boastr.net/).  It lets you maximize a window (coincidentally, true maximize rather than mac semi-random maximize) with ^⌘⌥ + up arrow.  It also offers half screen options as well, if you're interested in that, on top of the primary function (duplicating your menubar on a second monitor).  I believe that it is also offered in some way by BetterTouchTool, but I could be wrong on that and it's mostly aimed at the mouse, so it wouldn't help.

Disclaimer: I am in no way associated with SecondBar, just a satisfied user.

Answer (score 0):

I use [ShiftIt 1.2](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/Shift-It.shtml).
It is free, small and customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Move the mouse to the corner of the window where it becomes a resizing arrow and option double click to fill the screen, WITHOUT going into full screen mode.

More details:

Double clicking on any side when the resize arrow is visible will move that side to the edge of the screen. Adding option makes it affect the opposite side as well.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Thank, I will take that into account.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, as it had "just the keyboard" in it

Comment: True. I got excited at having discovered the shortcut and posted it in too many places. Also it was a duplicate, as noted in the previous comment. But, because it is a simple and almost unknown technique I'll leave it up — I found this question when I was trying to find a way to maximize macOS windows.