# Shortcut to maximise/restore windows in Macbook

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mac OS X Shortcut Maximize window](https://superuser.com/questions/148619/mac-os-x-shortcut-maximize-window)

What's the keyboard shortcut to maximise/restore windows in Macbook? Something similar to Windows where we can do this by double-clicking the top bar of the window.