# Maximize window to full screen on OS X

Tags: macos

I've got 2 questions regarding OS X. Firstly how do we maximize a window? (I mean I know the green button, but is there a way to tell the window to take all the remaining space available?)

Also, is there any way we could remove (or auto-hide) the menu bar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mac OS X Shortcut Maximize window](http://superuser.com/questions/148619/mac-os-x-shortcut-maximize-window)

Comment: ok just to be sure. i can't achieve it without downloading installing anything extra?

Comment: No you can't. The green button usually switches between user state and optimum state, as determined by the application developer. If they say "optimum is full screen" (.e.g Apple Mail), then you're good. Otherwise, you're not. With 24+ inch screens, full screen is a ridiculous waste of space anyway. You could e.g. Cinch for the Windows 7 experience of dragging windows to the very top to maximize them. That's what I do.

Comment: 24 inch..  think about laptoppers..

Comment: I can only give you the options you have, and a possible explanation why it is like it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/148619/mac-os-x-shortcut-maximize-window).

For the second question: No. This is the menu bar and is always there, except for some full-screen applications, where it's hidden or on auto-hide. There are some hacks to get around that, but what's the point? You need it all the time anyway.

Comment: ok is there a way to get it to the left or right side? because having a bar at the top makes clicking the tabs in chromes very hard (i couldn't just fling my pointer upwards)

Comment: @Pacerier No, there isn't. Is it just Chrome you're concerned about?

Comment: @Daniel Beck yea partly..         .

Comment: @Pacerier Check out Megazoomer. It's a bit intrusive, using SIMBL and stuff, but might work for you. Haven't tried it with Chrome though. I can't look up the configuration for full screen programs right now, unfortunately. Will look it up in 5 hours when I'm home.

Comment: heys cool, btw its ok. if it requires installing/downloading something else then I'm not doing it. i just don't believe in it, its not portable at all

Comment: @Pacerier Megazoomer does, but changing Chrome configuration doesn't. Still somewhat laborious if you're not used to it.

Comment: @Pacerier I just tried [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070118003804854) but the Chrome tabs still aren't at the very top, and you need to get the pointer back to prevent the menubar from reappearing. I suggest you learn the `Cmd-Opt-Left/Right` and `Cmd-[Number]` keyboard shortcuts instead.

Comment: what if you move the tabs in chrome? it now has the option to move them to the left or right side

Comment: @acme Not too long ago that option was pretty unpolished (to put it mildly) on OS X.

Comment: @Daniel Beck oic cool didn't know of the shortcuts

Answer (score 3):

Just hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while pressing the Green Icon to go to full screen.

This works with OS X 10.8.2+

Answer (score 2):

I have assigned this script to ⌘M with FastScripts:

```
try
    tell application "Finder" to bounds of window of desktop
    tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
        set bounds of window 1 to result
    end tell
on error
    try
        tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where it is frontmost)
            click (button 1 of window 1 where subrole is "AXZoomButton")
        end tell
    end try
end try
```

It doesn't work with multiple displays though.

Applications that support maximizing windows to fill the screen:

- [BetterSnapTool](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12)
- [BetterTouchTool](http://boastr.de)
- [Breeze](http://autumnapps.com/breeze)
- [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy)
- [Flexiglass](http://nulana.com/flexiglass)
- [iKey](http://plumamazing.com/mac/ikey/)
- [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/)
- [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/)
- [NuKit](http://nulana.com/nukit)
- [OptimalLayout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/)
- [QuicKeys](http://quickeysonline.com/mac)
- [RightZoom](http://www.blazingtools.com/right_zoom_mac.html)
- [SecondBar](http://blog.boastr.net)
- [ShiftIt](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt)
- [SizeUp](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/)
- [SizeWell](http://www.sizewellplugin.com)
- [Slate](https://github.com/jigish/slate)
- [WrongZoom](https://github.com/spicyj/wrongzoom/)

Comment: The `LSUIPresentationMode` doesn't help in this case, since the tabs are still not at the very top and the menubar reappears. Feels like the Windows start menu button pre XP *shudder*.

Answer (score 0):

As a new Mac user, I was also looking for a Maximise button - not Full Screen exactly, as I don't want to lose visibility of the system bar or the Dock.

Seems that simply **double clicking the title bar** of any app does exactly what I need.