# Windows open maximized by default?

Tags: macos

I'm new to developing on Mac OS X; my usual dev environment is Ubuntu GNU/Linux with the StumpWM tiling window manager.  I'm used to starting an app and having it take up 100% of the screen real estate.

My question is: is there any way to configure Mac OS X 10.6 (either natively or using a third-party app) to default to open every new window in maximized state?

Comment: Probably not possible. But most apps remember the bounds of the previously closed window. And you can assign a shortcut to [Maximize window to full screen on OS X - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/278452/maximize-window-to-full-screen-on-os-x)

Comment: Thanks - yeah I feared it wasn't but hoped someone on SU might know a way.  Apple has changed a bit since the days of the IIe :-/

Answer (score 4):

Somehow most other software I use opens up maximized anyway, possibly because I use [ShiftIt](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt) and <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-Cmd M</kbd> a lot (and most software seems to remember the previously used window size). The only thing I use a lot that didn't open maximimized was iTerm2.

You can get [iTerm2](http://iterm2.com/) to open in a maximized window by going to Preferences -> Profiles -> Window and setting a high number of Columns and Rows.

[image: iTerm2 preferences screenshot]

I know this is not a completely satisfying answer to the question but it seems there is none on OS X.